# значение макс превышения рельефа в каждом полигоне

Tags: gis, arcgis

arcmap 10.6.1
данные:
есть территория-растр
есть полигоны созданные на основе 1-градусной сетки с внешним буфером 8км, таким

образом получились накладывающиеся полигоны.
Вопрос:!!!
Как получить значение максимального превышения рельефа в каждом полигоне?
Сразу скажу, что zonal statistics as table дает некорректные значения. К такому

выводу пришли путем сравнения значений превышений в полигонах с буфером и 1-

градусной сетки, где значения большего полигона всегда должны быть выше или равные, а на деле получаются и ниже.

Comment: хоть кросс-постинг и не приветствуется в рамках stackexchange, однако советую спросить тут https://gis.stackexchange.com/

Comment: значения не должны быть выше или равны - с чего вы взяли обратное?